# encoding not working IE vs Firefox, wordpress latest v

Tags: wordpress

I have latest wordpress version installed and this is driving me nuts!!!

It renders well in firefox but in IE it doesnt!!

http://www.mais-saude.net/

please see if you can help with the problem, what should I do ? wp-config is set to utf-8 as so is the "reading" in options page in wordpress admin area.

What next? why is this happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Appearance -> Editor in your admin panel and there change the header.php

Change

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
```

To

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When opening the page in internet Explorer, Although the page rendered but not in the correct way, I found that Explorer was signaling an error at the bottom. Here it is:

```
Error details of the web page

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0, Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2,. NET CLR 2.0.50727;. NET CLR 3.5.30729;. NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2;. NET CLR 1.1.4322)
Timestamp: Fri, January 6, 2012 4:14:23 p.m. UTC


Message: Syntax error
Line: 1
Character: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.mais-saude.net/wp-content/themes/constellation1.1/constellationjs/plugins.js?ver=3.3.1


Message: Syntax error
Line: 1
Character: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.mais-saude.net/wp-content/themes/constellation1.1/constellationjs/script.js?ver=3.3.1
```

It is saying that there is a syntax error in your JavaScript.
Are you sure your code is correct? if yes, see if there are some incompatibilites between IE and wordpress

Comment: @janw his theme comes from **Wordpress**. do you see the **wp** in wp-content? it refers to wordpress.

Comment: I see /wp-content/themes/ which is the default directory for any template. And its not teh default twentyten or twentyeleven

Comment: this template (and it's css/js) is not a default part of wordpress. The folder it is stored in is irrelevant. It's the default folder. Your link doesn't tell me anything.... Do you even know how a WP template works?

Comment: yes I do, your missing the point, I'm talkign about character encoding! the utf-8 bable, it's not working

Comment: Now you are making sence, thats a option in the wp-admin->settings->reading.still has nothing to with the folder....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that IE doesn't support mediaquery's. IE doesn't isn't wide enough for some reason.
MAke the body on the CSS wider around line 476.

In FF the same will happen if you make your window smaller